# Why wont the apache localhost directory work?

Tags: php, apache

My apache is not display any webpage what so ever when I am trying to connect to the website I am creating through localhost.

I was told that I should be able to connect through localhost/www/[webpage folder]/index.php but when I do so the error that I receive is:

> ## Not Found
>
> The requested URL /www/wws/index.php was not found on this server.

Its awkward because I can connect to the website/page by using the directory,             `file:///C:/wamp/www/wws/index.php`but it does not show any of the code inside of the webpage. It is just blank and solid white. The php include is defiantly setup correctly as I have had another question regarding that and no answers were proven right as I believe it is because of apache. Not sure if it's the conf of the apache folder or what. (I have not touched the conf after installing it)

I'm not sure what it could be because the file is most defiantly there.

Any answers would be appreciated as I need to figure this out to get going on the site.

Comment: I've fixed it for you, but in future please provide error messages in the question instead of linking to screenshots of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http URL does not work because, presumably, the root directory of the site is `c:\wamp\www` so you should not include `www/` in the URL.

The file URL does not work because PHP is, in this context, a server side programming language and you are accessing the file directly with the browser instead of requesting it from the server.

Comment: Alright how would I go about requesting it from the server instead? When I just put a basic `<p>` tag inside of the index.php instead of using the `php include` it will display that fine.

Comment: What do you mean requesting it from the server instead? You're always requesting the HTML from the server.

Comment: @NobleUplift — No. With a `file:` URL you are ignoring the Apache server and reading it directly from the hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

look for the httpd.conf file, and check if the DocumentRoot is set to where you want to.

Like, if document root is set to:

c:\

The folder

c:\www\wws\

will answer the url:

localhost/www/www

Got the idea?

Comment: You mean URL `localhost/www/wws`.

Comment: Got the idea, When I have changed the document root to

`"localhost/wamp/www/"` 

It did nothing different and gave me the same error trying to reach the page at `localhost/wamp/www/wws/index.php`